# How can custom values be passed from a DRF ModelViewSet to a permissions class?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions, django-rest-viewsets

I've set up a [custom permissions class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) to be reused from multiple views, in an app where some users have ownership-like rights on behalf of other users:

```
class IsOwnerLike(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if (
            user_is_owner(request.user, request.data["owned_by"])
            | user_is_owner_like(request.user, request.data["owned_by"])
        ):
            return True

        return False
```

This works as expected for one ModelViewSet.

However, for legacy reasons, different requests coming in to different views may not have an "owned_by" data element -- it may be called "owned", "owner", "created_by", etc. -- and therefore I can't reuse this custom permission as written.

What is the correct way to abstract things at the viewset, to normalize  data being passed to my custom permissions class? Can this be done, or should I be thinking about handling these permissions differently?

Comment: if you use created_by then it wont work, you have to create the differnet  permission class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution.

I was able to add a custom attribute to the view:

```
class ViewOne(ModelViewSet):
    ownership_fieldname = "owned_by"
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerLike]

    ...

class ViewTwo(ModelViewSet):
    ownership_fieldname = "owner"
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerLike]
    ...
```

And then access it in the permission:

```
class IsOwnerLike(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if (
            user_is_owner(request.user, request.data[view.ownership_fieldname])
            | user_is_owner_like(request.user, request.data[view.ownership_fieldname])
        ):
            return True

        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use from has_object_permission for object check for model access permission like this:

```
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'owner'):
           if obj.user == request.user:
              return True
        return False
```

you can change owner with your models owner field name

and for pass owner kwargs to permission class you should write custommModelViewSet and inheritance from ModelViewSet and override get_permissions() method

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In this case I'm dealing with a POST request, so the object doesn't exist yet. This permissions test is intended to determine a users' right to create the object.

Comment: so you can call check_permission in perform create